# How can I rewrite this conditional statement to be shorter?

Tags: javascript

I have a conditional statement with an && and || clause but I would like to shorten and clean this up. Would the best course of action be to rewrite this inside of an array? Should I also turn this into a ternary operator?

Thanks for your help

```js
if ((V1_CCLS == "S06") && ((V1_CCCT === "") || (VS_SELQ == "LED_COUNT_CRNR"))) {
   V1_CCCT = V1_CCLS;
}
```

Comment: We don't know what values can be your variables. But your look good. Any sense to change it I mean.

Comment: There are three values with three different conditions in this expression. This hardly gets any shorter than this. The only chance is to refactor this entire code. Which you should probably do anyway, just judging by the variable names.

Comment: if we go by Clean Code book (: so I would like to make enumerators and replace this strings with enumerated fields. so it's not always good to shorted - You're losing readability, better think about how to make it easy for eyes and make it easy to extend in future (for example by moving to external util function)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to read if you put it into a variable or function and name is something descriptive so whoever is reading it knows quickly what is going on.

Also, you want to use parentheses with the same rules as algebra. Putting parentheses around (V1_CCLS == "S06") isn't needed, for instance.

For example:

```
let isReady = V1_CCLS === "S06" && (V1_CCCT === "" || VS_SELQ === "LED_COUNT_CRNR");

if (isReady) {
    V1_CCCT = V1_CCLS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a ternary for this case. I'd just make it a bit more readable by displaying the conditions on separate lines.

```
if (
    V1_CCLS == "S06" &&
    (
        V1_CCCT === "" ||
        VS_SELQ == "LED_COUNT_CRNR"
    )
) V1_CCCT = V1_CCLS;
```

Comment: idea is that if CCLS chosen S06 then to check other conditionals, so Your answer is wrong.

Comment: right, I changed my response to match your suggestion

Comment: again logic is incorrect: if S06 chosen and CCCT is empty then do it, but what if CCCT not empty? it will execute body without checking VS_SELQ value

Comment: good, but better to move some function which will do that check logic (:  like: `if (isSomeCondition({V1_CCLS, V1_CCCT, VS_SELQ}) V1_CCCT = V1_CCLS`

Comment: That would make it more like functional programming right ?

Answer (score -1):

V1_CCCT = (V1_CCLS == "S06") && (!V1_CCCT) || (VS_SELQ == "LED_COUNT_CRNR")) ? V1_CCLS : ""

Comment: `V1_CCCT === ""` is not the same as `!V1_CCCT` and ternary is not shortening

Comment: !V1_CCCT will return true

Comment: `!V1_CCCT` is true when: `V1_CCCT` is `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN` and anything, so person is checking strictly `=== ""` which is different logic